# How to trim a string after a specific character in java

Tags: java

I have a string variable in java having value:

```
String result="34.1 -118.33\n<!--ABCDEFG-->";
```

I want my final string to contain the value:

```
String result="34.1 -118.33";
```

How can I do this? I'm new to java programming language.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use:

```
result = result.split("\n")[0];
```

Comment: if you're only interested in the first element, you can `split("\n", 2)[0];` to increase performance.

Comment: @jlordo sweet! I didn't know about the 2nd optional parameter - thanks!

Answer (score 37):

Assuming you just want everything before `\n` (or any other literal string/char), you should use [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) with [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

```
result = result.substring(0, result.indexOf('\n'));
```

If you want to extract the portion before a certain regular expression, you can use [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
result = result.split(regex, 2)[0];
```

---

```
String result = "34.1 -118.33\n<!--ABCDEFG-->";

System.out.println(result.substring(0, result.indexOf('\n')));
System.out.println(result.split("\n", 2)[0]);
```

```
34.1 -118.33
34.1 -118.33
```

(Obviously `\n` isn't a meaningful regular expression, I just used it to demonstrate that the second approach also works.)

Comment: Thanks for learning me a nice usage of `<pre>` tag on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 15):

There are many good answers, but I would use [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). I find `StringUtils.substringBefore()` more readable than the alternatives:

```
String result = StringUtils.substringBefore("34.1 -118.33\n<!--ABCDEFG-->", "\n");
```

Answer (score 6):

Use regex:

```
result = result.replaceAll("\n.*", "");
```

`replaceAll()` uses regex to find its target, which I have replaced with "nothing" - effectively deleting the target.

The target I've specified by the regex `\n.*` means "the newline char and everything after"

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String result = "34.1 -118.33\n<!--ABCDEFG-->";
result = result.substring(0, result.indexOf("\n"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Scanner` and pass in the delimiter and the original string:

```
result = new Scanner(result).useDelimiter("\n").next();
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(result);
String line = scanner.nextLine();//will contain 34.1 -118.33
```

Comment: Never thought about using `nextLine()` in this case...but my solution works on all delimiters, not just newlines (and other line separators).

Comment: @gparyani yes, but in this case `nextLine` is enough :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use   `result = result.replaceAll("\n","");`
or

```
 String[] split = result.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **StringTokenizer**:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("34.1 -118.33\n<!--ABCDEFG-->", "\n");
System.out.println(st.nextToken());
```

**output**:

```
34.1 -118.33
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest method you can do and reduce your efforts.
just paste this function in your class and call it anywhere:

> you can do this by creating a substring.

**simple exampe is here:**

```js
public static String removeTillWord(String input, String word) {
    return input.substring(input.indexOf(word));
}

removeTillWord("Your String", "\");
```