# Truncate a variable using JavaScript within an html file

Tags: javascript, variables, trim

I want to trim the "description" variable in an html file to remove the price, using javascript.

A typical description would be "hat, red - $5.99"  In all cases, the price -that is,everything after the "$" should not display.

Here is what the html code looks like:

```
<tr class="font1">
        <td valign="top" align="left" width="15%">[id]</td>
        <td valign="top" align="left" width="53%">[description]  
</tr>
```

This solution ([How to trim a string after a specific character in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220022/how-to-trim-a-string-after-a-specific-character-in-java)") eemed to come close, but I'm not sure how to implement this code within my file.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want `$5.99` or `hat, red` from `hat, red - $5.99`? Please confirm again.

Answer (score 1):

1) "Java" and "JavaScript" are different things. The "split" concept is still the way you want to go, but the syntax is different.

2) If you want to access and manipulate the HTML contents, it's generally a good idea to use a class (repeatable for multiple elements) or a unique id (only 1 on the page) for the elements you want to change. Your HTML currently doesn't seem to have this, so the only option would be to grab ALL `<td>` elements and remove every price across the board. If that's what you want, score! If not, then you'd need to consider adding a class for a selected cell or something like that.

3) Once you have a way to grab the contents, you can search the description for a "$" and put everything prior to it in a new string that you put into the cell.

```
    //returns every td element, since you have no classes or ids
    var allCells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

    //loop through the list of td elements
    for (var i=0; i < allCells.length; i++) {

        //get the actual HTML content of the cell 
        var currentCellText = allCells[i].innerHTML;

        //split the description text at the '$' and replace the table cell contents            
        var newText = currentCellText.split('$')[0];
        allCells[i].innerHTML = newText;

    }
```

Note that this assumes a few things:

- There is only 1 "$" in the description
- That the price always comes after everything else you want to keep & there's nothing after you need
- That the descriptions are relatively short. If you have 1000 words before the "$" this approach would not be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to split your string at the `$`, you can use the [String.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function with the `$` as the deliminator.

Example:

```
var fullDescription = 'hat, red $5.99';
var description = fullDescription.split('$')[0] //Split returns an array of the string divided on either side of the $, so take the first element.
```

The variable `description` will now hold `'hat, red '`.