# How to trim textview after specific character?

Tags: java, android, text, textview, trim

This is the format of my app

TextView1
Button1
Textview2

The value of my textview1 is ABCD?1234

I want to remove all characters starting from "?" After I click the button1

So that the value of my second textview become ABCD only.

I hope you understand my problem
Im very new to java programming.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that this is a very basic problem where the solution to your problem is just a google search away. Took me one search (i.e. 10 seconds) to find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220022/how-to-trim-a-string-after-a-specific-character-in-java) where multiple solutions can be found. Please only ask questions on Stack Overflow if you tried solving it first.

Comment: Please don't address stack overflow as "sir".

Answer (score 0):

check out `split` method from `String` class

```
String[] splitted = textview1.getText().toString().split("\\?");
splitted[0]; // "ABCD"
splitted[1]; // "1234"
textview2.setText(splitted[1]);
```

you need to escape `?` by adding `\\` before, because `split` method takes regex and `?` have some meaning in regex, isn't "usual" character